# How to upload multiple projects in separate folders to the same repository?

Tags: git

I have multiple projects in separate folders. It looks as following on the disk:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I already created remote repository and uploaded one project. It looks as following:

[image]

How to upload the second project in its separate folder to the same repository?

Comment: Why do you want separate repositories locally but a unified repository upstream?  And how do you plan to keep all this in sync?

Comment: It's a request.

Comment: `git` tracks full trees, and operates on the entire history of the repository.  If you already have two repositories, I'm pretty sure you'd need to merge (`git merge --allow-unrelated-histories`) them locally, then push that up.  You're going to have a hard time keeping the repositories unified upstream but separate locally.

Answer (score 0):

FIrst create subdirectory in local repo

```
mkdir png
```

then add files ( and move then into subdirectory)

```
git add *.png
git mv  *.png ./png
```

commit  and push

```
 git commit -m "move"
 git push -u origin main
```

If you already have folders then

```
git add /png/*.png
git commit -m "c"
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: I already have 2 separate folders.